# DB2 RowNumber equality check in When clause

Tags: db2, olap, row-number

I am starter on DB2.

when I develop query I met a problem with error code
SQLCODE=-120, SQLSTATE=-42903

under query is that.

```
SELECT PHYSICAL_NAME||''
  FROM DEV_RESOURCE
  WHERE RESOURCE_ID = '40069684046725203038312337393001'
  AND ROWNUMBER() OVER() = 1 --This line is problem.
  WITH UR
```

I think compare ROWNUMBER() OVER() and 1 is problem.
How to fix it?

In oracle than query(ROWNUMBER() OVER() -> ROWNUM) is work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple options. If you just want to return a single row, you could do:

```
SELECT PHYSICAL_NAME||''
  FROM DEV_RESOURCE
  WHERE RESOURCE_ID = '40069684046725203038312337393001'
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
  WITH UR
```

DB2 has the above syntax, but also understands MySQL syntax (LIMIT). Another option is to rewrite the query like this:

```
SELECT PHYSICAL_NAME||''
  FROM (select rownumber() over() as rn, DR.* from 
  DEV_RESOURCE DR 
  WHERE RESOURCE_ID = '40069684046725203038312337393001')
  WHERE RN=1
  WITH UR
```

There are more options, depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use rownumber into where clause, only after execution of query. Try something like this :

```
 select * from (
     SELECT PHYSICAL_NAME||'' as PHYSICAL_NAME,
     ROWNUMBER() OVER() as rang
     FROM DEV_RESOURCE
     WHERE RESOURCE_ID = '40069684046725203038312337393001'
 ) tmp
where tmp.rang=1
```